# "Downloading external resources is Disabled" Error in testng.xml file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am practice selenium webdriver test automation project using testng framework. In my  estng.xml file I was getting error like "Downloading external resources is Disabled " Error.
[Error in Testng.XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWAgF.png)

I tried  navigate to Window----->Preferences------>XML(Wild Web Developer) and checked Download external resources like referenced DTD,XSD checkbox then above Error got Resolved but ON Running my project as testng suite I am getting [WARN]message in Eclipse console like "[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected."
What should I do next to avoid this WARN message

[WARN Message in Eclipse Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u29N1.png)

[Setting Download external resources like referenced DTD,XSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQPG0.png)